# Array from database to editable form

Tags: php, sql, database, mariadb

I want to make a form where I can edit information from an array I get from my database. And then put them in a form with strings so I can edit the values of each category from the database and then send the changed information to the database. When I use this command

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=mariadb.spectrogon.local;dbname=gitter;charset=utf8', 'gitter_in', 'gitter_in');
$sql = "call hämta_artikel_info('715.702.930')";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$printable = $result->fetchAll();
print_r($printable);
```

I get the following array back

```
     (
        [artikel_nr] => 715.702.930
        [0] => 715.702.930
        [points] => 50x50 5 
        [1] => 50x50 5 
        [points2] => 50x50 5 
        [2] => 50x50 5 
        [scale] => 1 + 0.75
        [3] => 1 + 0.75
        [energy] => 70
        [4] => 70
        [value] => 5.000
        [5] => 5.000
        [nollan] =>
        [6] =>
        [approved_from] =>
        [7] =>
        [approved_to] =>
        [8] =>
    )
```

Now I would like to put all the info I've got from this array and put it in a form. Then I would be able to edit that information

The following SQL: `" call hämta_artikel_info(715.702.930)"` as far as I know should be a `select`procedure

My full code atm.

```
    <?php

echo "test";

error_reporting(E_All);
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);



$db = mysqli_connect('mysql:host=mariadb.spectrogon.local;dbname=gitter;charset=utf8', 'gitter_in', 'gitter_in');
$connection = new Connection;
$db = $connection->openConnection();

$stmt = $db->prepare("call hämta_artikel_info('715.702.930')");
$stmt->execute();
print_r($stmt);



echo "
    while($results = $stmt->fetch()){  
    <form name='form' method='post' action=''>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><input type='text' name='id' readonly class='form-control-plaintext' value=" . $results['artikel_nr'] ."></td>
<td><input type='submit' name='update' value='Update' class='form-control'></td>";



 if(isset($_POST['update']))
{    
    $var= $_POST['var'];
    if(empty($var){
   echo"variable is empty ";
}

    else {    
        $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE table_name SET col_name='" .$var. "'");
}
 $stmt->execute();
        @header("Location: stackoverflow.php");
    }
}


?>
```

Keep in mind that I'm very new to programming so would really appreciate detailed explanations.

Comment: Looks kinda wrong this while cycle in echo, you should have your "echo form" inside while cycle, not the twisted way. Try it - while($results = $stmt->fetch(){ echo "...";}

Comment: Still does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
echo "<form name='form' method='post' action =''>
         <tbody>";
     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>    
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='id' readonly class='form-control-plaintext' value="<?php echo $row['artikel_nr'];?>">
        </td>

    <?php}
    echo "<td>
            <input type='submit' name='update' value='Update' class='form-control'>
        </td>
    </tbody>
</form>";
```